# How do you convert a Vec<String> to a &[&str] of a fixed character?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I can't seem to figure out how to convert a Vec into an equivalent length &[&str] with a fixed character. For example, I want to convert something like ["hello", "world"] to something of the form  &[&"@", &"@"].

When I try to do:

```
let x:Vec<String> = vec!["hello", "world"];
let mapped = x.into_iter().map(|s| "@").collect();
```

the compiler says:

```
a value of type `&[_]` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str` the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for `&[_]`
```

What is the correct way of converting a `Vec<String>` into a `&[&str]` of a singled fixed character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it since `[&str]` has no definite size. Try explicitly collecting into a `Vec<&str>` and then call `as_slice` on it:

```
let x = vec!["hello", "world"];
let mapped = x
   .iter()
   .map(|s| "@")
   .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
   .as_slice();
```

Also take a look at [Rust's ad-hoc conversions table](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv) as it says that `as_slice()` is cost-free so it should be perfectly fine to use it here I guess.

Comment: Doesn't work if the `mapped` value is ever used - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a4c98a442ba0a09cc5d30c8b5224364.

Comment: It's interesting that it works when it isn't used. But yeah, need to separate that to two lines.